# Azure Policy - matching with wildcards from an array parameter

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Im having a play with Azure Policy and looking to setup a policy which enforces a specific naming convention for resource groups. I've got it working as i want when using a spefic single naming convention, but i wanted to try and improve the functionality by using a parameter specified as an array which could contain multiple allowed naming formats, so for example pass a parameter when assigning the policy that says the resource group name could be either PROD-RG-???? or TEST-RG-???? for example, or PROD-RG-* / TEST-RG-*.

now i know you can't use wildcards with the match command, but i can't seem to use a match from within the array. If i use match or like it expects the parameter to be a string rather than an array.

I wasn't sure if i may be able to do this with the count command?

What other ways do i have of doing this?

```
{
"properties": {
  "displayName": "Test Resource Group Naming Convention",
  "policyType": "Custom",
  "mode": "All",
  "metadata": {
    "version": "1.0.0",

  },
  "parameters": {
      "allowedRGNames": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
              "displayName": "Allowed Resource Group Naming Convention",
              "description": "The allowed resource group naming convention. Use # for a number, ? for a letter or . for any character. Or specify specific characters to use."
          }
      }
  },
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/ResourceGroups"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "name",
                 "like": "[parameters('allowedRGNames')]"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }
},
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use *value count* (details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#policy-rule):

```json
{
    "count": {
        "value": [ "prefix1_*", "prefix2_*" ],
        "name": "pattern",
        "where": {
            "field": "name",
            "like": "[current('pattern')]"
        }
    },
    "greater": 0
}
```